# How can I read Emails in Grails?

Tags: grails

I want to parse mails that are send to an IMAP mailbox from my Grails application.

I tried this plugin: https://github.com/IntelliGrape/Grails-Mail-Watcher-Plugin but it does not provide all the functionality I need.

Edit: I need to get the following information from my inbox:

- the number of mails
- the number of unread mails
- the number of read mails
- a way to iterate over each mail

I need from the mail:

- sender
- receiver
- subject
- date
- mail body
- mail attachments
- mail attachment types
- if it is html or plain text mail

**How can I read the mails and get the sender, subject, body and attachments?**

Comment: so what exactly are your requirements then? As i see in the mail watcher plugin here: https://github.com/IntelliGrape/Grails-Mail-Watcher-Plugin/blob/master/grails-app/domain/org/grails/plugins/mailwatcher/Email.groovy you can get exact these information

Answer (score 1):

as i'm not aware of any particular plugin, other the one you already mentioned, you could use the [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otncn) directly. One example of this usage can be found [here](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/06/reading-email-using-javamail-api-example.html#.U5oQsZR_tzo). The other opportunity is, that you could either extend this plugin (the entry point should be [here](https://github.com/IntelliGrape/Grails-Mail-Watcher-Plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugins/mailwatcher/EmailReaderService.groovy)). The plugin uses the Java Mail API internally as well.